# Adding a function to keyword values

Tags: clojure

i have a map structure like this...

```
    {"email@gmail.com"{:email "email@gmail.com", :password "pass"},
    "email2@yahoo.com"{:email "email2@yahoo.com", :password "pass2"},
    "email3@yahoo.com"{:email "email3@yahoo.com", :password "pass3"},
    "email4@gmail.com"{:email "email4@gmail.com", :password "pass4"}}
```

how can i add a function to all values in refering to :password keyword?my function has a parameter that accepts only strings...this is what i tried but couldn't got around it...

(update-in mymap [:password] (myfunction "here were suppose to be values from :password keyword"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update each line separately and accumulate, so iterate with `reduce` over the list, then for each element `update-in` the `password` key and `assoc` the resulting row to the result.

```
(reduce (fn[result row] 
          (assoc result  
                 (first row) ;;email
                 (update-in (second row) 
                            [:password] 
                            (fn[pass] ..do something..))))
        {}
        mymap)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(reduce-kv (fn [result k cfg-map]
             (assoc result
               k (update-in cfg-map [:password] your-fn)))
           {} your-ds)
```

or

```
(into {} (mapv #(update-in % [1 :password] your-fn) your-ds))
```